How to mock a child component to test the parent behavior after callback
I have a react web application written in typescript using vitest testing library.
I have a parent component and a child form component with a callback to the parent when form fields are updated. If the form data is valid, the submit button will be enabled. I have written unit tests to test the presence of button and to test that it is disabled initially. I would like to test the button being enabled upon valid form data.
Here's a simplified version of my implementation.
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [isFormDataValid, setIsFormDataValid] = useState(false)

    const onFormDataChanged = (e: any) => {
        if (checkFormValidity(e)) {
            // consume form data
            setIsFormDataValid(true)
        } else {
            setIsFormDataValid(false)
        }
    }

    return (
       ...
       <ChildFormComponent formScope={formScopeArr} value={formAutofillData} onChange={onDataChanged} />
       ...
       <SubmitButton disabled={!isFormDataValid} onClick={onSubmitButtonClicked} >
            Submit
       </SubmitButton>
    )
}

Child component looks similar to this
export type Props = {
    value?: any,
    onChange?: (value: any) => void
    formScope?: []
}

export function ChildFormComponent({ value, onChange, formScope }: Props) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState<formDataType>({
        name: undefined,
        phone: undefined,
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        if (onChange) {
            onChange(formData)
        }
    }, [formData])

    return (
       ...set form data change in formData
    )
}


My initial tests work like this:
    it('should display button with text Submit', () => {
        render(
                <ParentComponent />
        )
        const buttons = screen.getAllByRole('button') as [HTMLButtonElement]
        const button = buttons[buttons.length - 1]
        expect(button.textContent).toEqual("Submit")
    })
    it('should render disabled button initially', () => {
        render(
                <ParentComponent />
        )
        const buttons = screen.getAllByRole('button') as [HTMLButtonElement]
        const button = buttons[buttons.length - 1]
        expect(button.disabled).toBeTruthy()
    })

I tried to use fireevent to trigger a form update but the data I pass using fireevent is not being passed to the parent component.
I couldn't find any resources to mock this child component so that I can trigger the callback with valid form data.
Is there anyway I can successfully test this?
